# How do I solve CORS Policy error with .NET 6 and React?

Tags: reactjs, .net, cors

I am trying to call an API in the frontend, but I get this error instead:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5087/api/GetPlayerById/2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

- Frontend is running on `http://localhost:3000/` (React)
- Backend is running on `http://localhost:5087/` (.NET 6)
- API works on Postman
- API works on browser (Copy/Pasting the API on browser)
- CORS error appears when I call the API in React

I already looked at many post on CORS policy but none seems to help me. My last attemp was referring to [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Code so far (in .NET 6):

**Program.cs**

```
using tournament_manager_backend.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IPlayerRepository, PlayerRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMatchRepository, MatchRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;database=TournamentManager"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "http://localhost:5087,http://localhost:3000"
  }
}
```

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:19870",
      "sslPort": 44328
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "tournament_manager_backend": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5087",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know there are a lot of questions on this topic already but I have already changed the code many times from different sources that if I were to refer them here, it will make this post too long. I did the best I can to give you as much details as possible so that I can seek effective guidance. I will appreciate anyone helping. Thanks!

Comment: Neither Postman nor visiting the API directly is making a cross-origin request, so that's not telling you anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to include a `proxy` in the React server that you're using for development.  In your `package.json` include:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5087/",
```

as part of the top level parameters (i.e., no parent).  This creates a proxy through `http://localhost:3000/` to your back end.

Note that this is for development.  When you move to a "real" server you won't be using the React dev server for serving your front end code and there will likely be a different way to setup CORS.

Comment: Thank you! I was too focused on fixing it on the backend side.